# Why this switch case goes to the default case?

Tags: c, switch-statement

The code is supposed to check for a vowel input. If found, it would print "Vowel" and if there is none it should print "consonent". But the compiler is going to the `default` case regardless of the input and I can't find where the mistake is. Please Help.

Here's my code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char ch;
    printf("Insert a Char \n");
    scanf("%d", &ch);

    switch(ch)
    {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        printf("Vowel");
        break;

    default:
        printf("Consonent");
    }
}
```

Comment: read: https://www.dummies.com/programming/c/basics-of-the-scanf-function-in-c-programming/

Comment: it's consonant, not consonent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion specifier `%d` in this call

```
scanf("%d", &ch);
```

is invalid. It tries to read a number. So entering a letter like 'A' results in input error.

The compiler can issue a warning or even an error reporting that for example

> format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type
>   ‘char *’

Because using an invalid format can result in undefined behavior.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "ABCD";

    puts( s );

    scanf( "%d", ( int * )s );

    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

If for example even to enter a valid ASCII code as for example `65` of the letter `'A'` then the program output might look like

```
ABCD
A
```

That is the memory occupied by the array was overwritten.

Instead use the following call.(if you want to skip white spaces)

```
scanf( " %c", &ch );
```

or the following call

```
scanf( "%c", &ch );
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: What if you input a number between 97 and 122?

Comment: @usr2564301 There will be undefined behavior because an invalid conversion specifier is used with an object of the type char.

Comment: @usr2564301 no, it will work in the OPs code. 97=='a' is a true statement. Using 97 in vlad's code will reproduce the original issue I.e. the value of ch being 0

Comment: @LewisKelsey There will be undefined behavior because the memory that does not belong to the object of the type char can be overwritten.

Comment: @VladFromMoscow does it sign extend 97 to 4 bytes then when writing it to ch?

Comment: @LewisKelsey For example the used memory should be zeroed. So whether it will work or not depends on how internally the function is written. But in general it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @LewisKelsey Specially for you I appended my answer.:)

Answer (score 0):

you should use "%c" as the format. when you use "%d", the value is 0 (because no integers have been detected in the input string). Refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Example.

This issue, and `void main()` instead of `int main()`, should produce a compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

First thing **%d** accepts an integer, not a character so correct this and run then **place break after each case ends** if you don't place break it will run all case till the end which is the default.
Example:-

```
char ch;
printf("Insert a Char \n");
scanf("%c", &ch);

switch(ch)
{
case 'a':printf("Vowel");
    break;

case 'e':printf("Vowel");
    break;

case 'i':printf("Vowel");
    break;

case 'o':printf("Vowel");
    break;

case 'u':
    printf("Vowel");
    break;

default:
    printf("Consonent");
}
```

Hope it will help.
Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

> **Thanks Everyone. I appreciate the help!**
>   I should have noticed the data type though.

## include

void main()
{

```
char ch;
printf("Insert a Char \n");
scanf("%c", &ch);

switch(ch)
{
case 'a':
case 'A':

case 'e':
case 'E':

case 'i':
case 'I':

case 'o':
case 'O':

case 'u':
case 'U':
    printf("Vowel");
    break;

default:
    printf("Consonant");
}
```

}